# What are some applications where tree models perform better than neural networks?

Tags: neural-networks, comparison, decision-trees, random-forests, gradient-boosting

Neural networks are known to be generally better modeling techniques as compared to tree-based models (such as decision trees). Are there any exceptions to this?

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say in general. Speaking from my own experience and by looking at which models win Kaggle competitions (see [here](https://ndres.me/kaggle-past-solutions/) and [here](https://www.kaggle.com/rajiao/winning-solutions-of-kaggle-competitions)), I would say tree-based models e.g. Random Forests, Decision Trees, Gradient Boosting are favorable over neural networks when working with **low-dimensional data** and easy **interpretable features** (usually simple tabular data with numeric, ordinal or categorical features).

Whereas when working with everything high-dimensional like images, text, time series or other data with non-trivial features, I would recommend neural networks.

Of course there might be exceptions and the future may prove me wrong.